# Return or structure code so data from ajax call can be used in dynamically populated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

an answer from a previously question I asked here has posed another problem for me, as I am learning more and more about async calls I still can not figure out how to accomplish (as the previous answer showed me) a list which allows me to store and use data from a selected list item.

```
$('#home').live('pageshow', function(){
    // creating object 
    var customerList = JSON.parse('{"customerInAccount":[{"customer_name":"Jane Doe","auto_id":"21"},{"customer_name":"Jack   Black","auto_id":"22"}]}');

    // creating html string
    var listString = '<ul data-role="listview" id="customerList">';

    // running a loop
    $.each(customerList.customerInAccount, function(index,value){
     listString += '<li><a href="#" data-cusid='+this.auto_id+'>'+this.customer_name+'</a></li>';
    });
    listString +='</ul>';

    console.log(customerList);

    //appending to the div
    $('#CustomerListDiv').html(listString);

    // refreshing the list to apply styles
    $('#CustomerListDiv ul').listview();

    // getting the customer id on the click
    $('#customerList a').bind('click',function(){
     var customerID = $(this).data('cusid');  
     alert(customerID);
    });
});
```

with js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amEge/3/

This code works excellent and will allow me to accomplish what I want but fist I need to populate the customerList from a ajax call. But from the "success" function I cannot seem to get the code to work.

```
$.post(postTo,{id:idVar} , function(data) {

    customerList = data;
    //alert(customerList);
})
```

When I move the code inside the ajax function it dose not work. I was just wondering if anyone could help me and maybe show me how to deal with this from asynchronous calls ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you add a bit more information about the data source your are calling, the format it is responding with, the content type it is setting on the response, etc.

Comment: Please elaborate when you say it doesn't work, what happens? I can't see why it fails. Do you get any error messages? In the AJAX success handler, what happens when you try to alert, say customerList[0][0]?

Comment: See `post` response in firebug and extract with help of `find` whatever you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your page as below.

```
// I assume this is your dot net web service url
var webServiceURL = 'customer.asmx/GetCustomer';

// here home is your page's ID
$('#home').live('pageshow', function(){
    getCustomerList();

});

function getCustomerList(){
    param=JSON.strigify({id:'2'});
    callWebService(param, webServiceURL, onGetCustListSuccess, onGetCustListFailed)
}

function onGetCustListFailed(){
    alert("service request failed");
}

function onGetCustListSuccess(data, status){
    // creating object 
    // replace previous line with below
    // var customerList = JSON.parse('{"customerInAccount":[{"customer_name":"Jane Doe","auto_id":"21"},{"customer_name":"Jack   Black","auto_id":"22"}]}');
    var customerList = JSON.parse(data.d);

    // creating html string
    var listString = '<ul data-role="listview" id="customerList">';

    // running a loop
    $.each(customerList.customerInAccount, function(index,value){
     listString += '<li><a href="#" data-cusid='+this.auto_id+'>'+this.customer_name+'</a></li>';
    });
    listString +='</ul>';

    console.log(customerList);

    //appending to the div
    $('#CustomerListDiv').html(listString);

    // refreshing the list to apply styles
    $('#CustomerListDiv ul').listview();

    // getting the customer id on the click
    $('#customerList a').bind('click',function(){
     var customerID = $(this).data('cusid');  
     alert(customerID);
    });
}

function callWebService(param,url,successFunc,errorFunc){
    if(errorFunc=='undefined'){
        errorFunc=OnDataError;
    } 
    $.ajax({            
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: param,
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc,
            beforeSend:function(){$.mobile.loading( 'show' );},
            complete:function(){$.mobile.loading( 'hide');}
    });
}
```

Hope this would help you out. If you have problems asks me here.

Comment: OK it's still not working, I am alerting throughout your code just to understand the sequence of execution. But I am not getting into the callWebService function and also I don't understand the "successFunc" part of the code. Any more help would be appreciated, I am using the basic code layout from the previous answer you have given me. The .live function is working perfect so I believe I have the page structured properly. Also thanks for the answers, I am learning a lot from how you structure your code. Thanks

Comment: please check at which point the execution stops. Simple way to do that is placing an `alert('test1')` inside each function. Also press `f12` and see any errors logged in the console of your browser.

Comment: I alerted through the functions and noticed that the param variable was causing an error but didn't think it was the problem as I just using a fixed variable in the php script for debugging. Now I am getting an "Unexpected token u" on the JSON.parse(data.d) line of code.? Also why is it now named "data.d" ?

Comment: change the `data.d` to `data`. also log your response to console in success message as `console.log(data)` and tell me what you get. this might solve the problem

Comment: 'Object {customerInAccount: Array[2]}
customerInAccount: Array[2]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2'

Comment: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o meterTest.html:65
onGetCustListSuccess meterTest.html:65
k jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
y jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2
d jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2'

Comment: this means your webservice working just fine. You need to rewrite the success function that matches the service request. change this line `$.each(customerList.customerInAccount)...` to `$.each(customerList)...` and see what happens. Hope you removed the `data.d` to `data`

Comment: customerList.customerInAccount was correct just "data" did not need to be parsed (I presume because it is already returned parsed) maybe edit, your loop actually performs perfectly. Your knowledge is exceptional and I have once again learned a lot from your answer. I think this block of code will be useful for many people also. :)  Many thanks.

Comment: glad it worked. Seems your service returns Object array instead of the string. so I guess we don't have to parse. Anyway glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'll hazard a guess that your "live" code looks something like this:

```
$('#home').live('pageshow', function(){
   // creating object 
   var customerList;

   $.post(postTo, {id:idVar}, function(data) {
      customerList = data;
      //alert(customerList);
   });

   // creating html string
   var listString = '<ul data-role="listview" id="customerList">';

   // and all the rest...
```

If so, then your problem is that the code that's depending on your customerList variable being filled in ("all the rest...") runs immediately, rather than waiting for the response from your HTTP request to come back from the Web server.  That $.post() doesn't wait around (or "block," as we say in the computer software programming game) while the HTTP transaction makes its way to the Web server and back.  Instead, the rest of your code runs immediately, and then later, when that response comes back to the browser, the JavaScript engine dutifully executes your success function (or "closure," as we hm hmm hmmmm).

So what you'll want to do is put all this other code (the stuff that's dependent on customerList) into a separate function, then call that function from within your success closure.  You won't even need your customerList variable then; you can just pass the new response data as an argument to your new function.

Comment: You are 100% right, thanks you for explaining it so clearly. Very helpful.